# how to convert string into datetime format?

Tags: c#, datetime

```
string stringDate = "Mon May 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)"
```

I tried this but it's not working.

```
string date = "Mon May 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

I also tried this, but with the same error:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Is that meant to say "not working"? Try using `DateTime.ParseExact()`, specifying the format and culture explicitly. I don't think there's a specifier for the timezone bit in brackets though; the timezone offset part should be enough.

Comment: DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

I also try the code above but its the same error.

Comment: @Bridge: Even if OP would have heard of it, but what _is_ the format string for `DateTime.ParseExact`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's what I was unsure of, hence leaving a comment rather than an answer :-)

Comment: @MonicaNarvasa: Does your string look like `yearMonthDate`? No? Then "yyyyMMdd" won't do much good. ;-) Have a look at the documentation of `ParseExact` (which leads to [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)). Hint: Your format string should probably start with `ddd MMM`...

Comment: can you give me exact answer please?

Comment: @MonicaNarvasa what is the error? You say *the same error* a lot but never say what it is...

Answer (score 1):

Check [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and you able to find the answer by your self.

select valid date for testing, for example `Mon May 01 2000` is Monday? if not this will fail.

if you have `(China Standard Time)` also in your input string remove that first.

```
string date ="Mon May 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)".Split('(')[0].Trim();
```

you can use split method as above, and now you have date time string simile to  `"Mon 03 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0800"`

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'zzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```